# Django - Adding a part of a string onto a new line not working correctly

Tags: python, html, django

In my Django project, If the user makes a mistake when signing up, then an error is sent to my template and then displayed. Some of my error messages I send to the user are a bit lengthy, and therefore I want to start a new line within the text. I attempt to add **\n** within my text, however a new line isn't started.

Here's my code:
**views.py:**

```
return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'error': 'Username field must be \n a minimum of 5 characters'})
```

**signup.html:**

```
 {% if error %}
            <span class="errorspansignup"> {{ error }} </span>
    {% endif %}
```

The text I pass as *error* stays all on one line.

Does anybody know what the issue is? Thank you.

Comment: Have you try <br> instead of \n? Since it is html file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) filter

For example:

```
{{ error|linebreaks  }}
```

If **error** is `Username field must be \n a minimum of 5 characters`, the output will be `<p>Username field must be <br> a minimum of 5 characters</p>.`

Comment: `{{ value|linebreaksbr }}` from Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) if we want to avoid a _paragraph_ break.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways. 
1)Assuming that the `\n` in the passed dictionary corresponds to a newline and in html `\n` doesn't help much so can replace `\n` with `&13;`or `<br>` which will take the rest of the text to a newline. 
For this particular case you can try this:

```
return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'error': 'Username field must be &#13; a minimum of 5 characters'})
```

or

```
return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'error': 'Username field must be <br> a minimum of 5 characters'})
```

2)or you can try using CSS `whitespace` in the template setting it to pre-line or pre-wrap,which would wrap up the text according to the corresponding conditons. 
Here you can try this :

```
{% if error %}
        <span style="white-space: pre-line;"class="errorspansignup"> {{ error }} </span>
{% endif %}
```

Try this and see if any of the above two work.Feel free to ask further doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Working solution for the above situation:

Use `<br>` tag in the error string like below (**views.py**):

```
return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'error': 'Username field must be <br> a minimum of 5 characters'})
```

And use `richtext` filter in the template (**signup.html**):

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags ... %}
...
{% if error %}
        <span class="errorspansignup"> {{ error|richtext }} </span>
{% endif %}
```

**Note:** To load `richtext` filter we need to load `wagtailcore_tags`.